# Interrupt server thread when client closes TCP connection

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, tcp, server

I have a multithreaded TCP Server in Java which allows connections from several clients and starts a new ServerThread for each connected Client:

Server Class:

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    try {
        // Create a new thread for each incoming connection.
        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        ServerThread serverThread = new ServerThread(clientSocket, this);
        serverThread.run();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

After a specific timeout, a client closes its socket. How can I interrupt the ServerThread which was connected with the client? 
`clientsocket.isClosed()` and `!clientSocket.isConnected()` don't work for some reason.

Finally, I got it working with the following snippets (the solution is the socket in the resource block and the endless `in.readLine() == null`):

Server class

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            // Create a new thread for each incoming connection.
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            ServerThread serverThread = new ServerThread(clientSocket, this);
            serverThread.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ServerThread class:

```
public void run() {
    try (Socket socket = clientSocket; // Enable auto-close for socket...
         PrintWriter out = ...; BufferedReader in = ...;) {

        ...

        while (!clientSocket.isClosed() && !isInterrupted()) {
            if (in.readLine() == null) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Client with port " + clientSocket.getPort() + " closed connection to server.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Client class: I use the same try with resource block as in the ServerThread class

Comment: 1. You don't have a multithreaded server at all. You should be calling `serverThread.start()`, not `serverThread.run()`. At present you aren't creating any real threads at all. 2. The `isClosed()` and `isConnected()` methods tell you about the state of your socket, not about the state of the connection. They don't magically become false when the peer disconnects. 3. You don't need to interrupt the ServerThread. Reading from the socket returns end of stream in that case: are you testing for that?

Comment: But if I don't interrupt the ServerThread, there will be a huge amount of ServerThreads after some time.

Comment: The threads themselves recognize end of stream when reading, or IOExceptions when writing, or read timeouts, and close their sockets and exit. This is how all Java blocking-mode servers work. You need to read the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the client closes a TCP socket uncleanly without sending an explicit FIN (for example, if the client crashes) then the server will not know about it until it next tries to send a packet to the client (at which point the client will sent an RST packet to tell the server the socket was closed).

Assuming you have control of both client and server code, the most robust way to check the connection is to implement a heartbeat mechanism between the two so they are regularly pinging a small piece of data between them to check the validity of the connection.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain how to send FIN from the client before closing the connection?

Comment: Are you using standard Java?  It *should* send a FIN when you call socket.close() I believe.  You would need to check with something like Wireshark to see what's going on under the hood though.

Comment: Yes I use standard Java. Do I need to call a specifc method to receive the FIN from the client?

Comment: Do you mean I should try to open an InputStream?

Comment: @jannnik Of course you should open an input stream. How else is the server going to know what the client wants?

Answer (score 0):

Keep alive socket option is the standard way to watch persistent TCP connection. 
If your server was in the blocking read operation during the abort you'll get java.io.IOException: read failed. In the asynchronous case you'll receive read key with -1.
In the write state you'll get: Connection reset by peer: socket write error.
Just handle the exceptions or error codes to shutdown the thread if connection is not recoverable.

Comment: He is asking how to detect when the client closes the socket, and this doesn't answer it.